# How do I fetch all firebase data children at once?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When fetching `firebase` data from a certain `child` I write `Database.database().reference().child["mychild1"]...` But what if I want to fetch data from all the available children at the same time? I tried `Database.database().reference().child["mychild1"].["mychild2].["mychild3]...` but that didn't return anything? Is there a way to do this or do I need to fetch the data one child at a time?

***EDIT***
I omitted the `.child` as suggested. And while this is likely the way to fetch all data, I suddenly didn't get anything at all from `firebase`. Is there something additional from my `firebase` logic that needs to be changed?

```
extension Reactive where Base: DatabaseReference {
    func fetchFireBaseData() -> Observable<[Recipe]> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.base.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                guard let data = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
                let recipes = data.compactMap { dict -> Recipe? in
                    guard let value = dict.value as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
                    return Recipe(fbKey: dict.key,
                                  recipeImageObject: value[FbKeyName.image.description] as? String ?? "",
                                  recipeTextObject: value[FbKeyName.text.description] as? String ?? "",
                                  recipeHeaderObject: value[FbKeyName.header.description] as? String ?? "",
                                  isFavorite: UserDefaults.standard.favoriteRecipes.contains(dict.key))
                }
                observer.onNext(recipes)
                observer.onCompleted()
            })
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Database.database().reference()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#reference) returns a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference.html) object that represents the root of the entire database.  You can fetch this reference, which will get all of its children, recursively, into a single snapshot.  There is no need to use child() to get more specific references.  Bear in mind this snapshot will occupy memory using **all** of the data in the database, so for a big database, this could cause you to run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks! Although this surely how to do it, the logic in my code suddenly didn't return anything at all. Does omitting the children alter the way I should structure my logic? See edited question.